# How to create a Windows Service to run wso2server.bat

Tags: cmd, wso2, wso2-esb

I am relative new in WSO2 and are having some difficulties to solve some problems. Now I need to create a service, with run the wso2server.bat using wso2. However, when I search for a tutorial in the wso2 documentations I just find that:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service

With teach you to create a windows service starting from wso2 carbon. When I fetch for someone who had passed for the same problem, I wasn't able to found. Would someone explain how to do that?

Comment: and the issue was???

Comment: The tutorial just teach of how to create the service based on carbon.bat, i need to do the same in wso2server.bat. This tutorial doesn't work for this case. What i need to change in the code that i have to put in wrapper.conf? For example.

Comment: The question is still not clear.

Comment: When i create the Windows Service, based on that tutorial, he just run carbon.bat. I want run any other .bat, starting from this tutorial. How i change the code to do so, without have problems with the configurations? I create a new environment variable based on CARBON_HOME, for wso2server.bat? I change all the code? How can i do so? If you open the tutorial, you will see, that in wrapper.conf, he explain how to configurate YAJSW, to create the service based on carbon.bat. How can i do that for other archives?

Comment: I was able to solve my problem. The WSO2 have two tutorials, to each folder. One, from carbon.bat and integrator.bat, is the 'docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service'. Another is: 'docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service'. With serve for wso2server.bat. Now i am having another problem. I do what the tutorial teaches, and create de windows service. I start it and close the command prompts with the 'runConsole.bat' command, the link continue working in the first 10 seconds, later it stop's. How can i solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem.

The WSO2 have two tutorials, to each folder. One, from carbon.bat and integrator.bat, is the 'docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service‌​'. 
Another is: 'docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Installing+as+a+Windows+Ser‌​vice'. With serve for wso2server.bat.

Thank you everyone.